# Searching the fields 2 level above of associations using Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ransack

```
class UserGroup
 has_many :users
end
class User
 has_many :posts
end
class Post
end
```

Can we search the fields in user_group in the position of post using ransack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try something like `Post.ransack(user_user_group_type_eq: 'admin')`

here I am assuming UserGroup class will have a column `type` and comparing it to value `admin`